# Is there a way to attach a gesture translation to a blur effect?

Tags: ios, uiblureffect

In the same way one would apply a pan gesture translation to the alpha value of a view, for example, is there a way to attach a pan gesture translation to a blur effect?

To animate a blur effect, one may do this:

```
effectView.effect = blur

UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {

    effectView.effect = nil

})
```

This animates the blur from 100% blur to 0% blur. I have a pan gesture bound to this animation and can't figure out if there is a way to bind the translation to the blur effect. Is this even possible?

**More code**

```
@objc func gestureHandler(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation: CGPoint = gesture.translation(in: gesture.view)

    switch gesture.state {

    case .began:

        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: gesture.view)
        effectViewTo.effect = blur

    case .changed:

        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: gesture.view)
        someView.center = CGPoint(x: someView.center.x + translation.x, y: someView.center.y)
        // adjust blur here

    ...

}
```

Comment: Hello, Can you please share more code  ?

Comment: I added some more code and in it I showed how a translation can be bound to a view's positioning.

Comment: Please check in this link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator

Comment: I think this is best solutions for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/37613804/5514539