# Blur view with adjustable blur radius in UIKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, blur, uivisualeffectview

What is the UIKit equivalent of SwiftUI's Blur view. I'm aware of the visual effect view in UIKit, however we cannot adjust the blur radius in that.

SwiftUI Blur view:

```
struct Blur: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is some text.")
                .padding()
            Text("This is some blurry text.")
                .blur(radius: 2.0)
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible in UIKit?

Found a good answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/47475656/11515703

Comment: use : blurEffectView.alpha = 0.2. Just set alpha of ```UIVisualEffectView```

Comment: I tried that but the result is not great as you can't really notice the blur effect on lower alpha values.

Comment: @RajaKishan but you aren't supposed to change the alpha of `UIVisualEffectView`

Comment: Apple's docs explicitly say not to change the alpha of UIVisualEffectView

Comment: Found a good answer :https://stackoverflow.com/a/47475656/11515703